# How to change StackedBarChart Item Color in width of item in android

Tags: android

i have change orange color to green color and red color to blue color  and also i have to reduced width of each item please suggest me how to implement this i not able to found from which method we can change the color and width ?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.num.horizontalstckedbar.MainActivity">

    <com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts.StackedBarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StackedBarChart stackBarChart = (StackedBarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        List<ChartData> value = new ArrayList<>();

        Float[] value1 = {2f,3f,6f,5f };
        Float[] value2 = {3f,5f,7f,9f };

        value.add(new ChartData(value1, "Jone"));
        value.add(new ChartData(value2, "Joe"));

        List<String> h_lables = new ArrayList<>();
        h_lables.add("sun");
        h_lables.add("mon");
        h_lables.add("tue");
        h_lables.add("wed");

        stackBarChart.setHorizontal_label(h_lables);

        stackBarChart.setData(value);

        stackBarChart.setDescription("Stacked bar Chart");

    }
```

using this code i am able to plot the graph Stacked bar chart : like below

[image]